# Correct comma placement in this sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

> Consider x, when the regulator is set to zero the integrand in x reduces to y.

Is this the correct comma placement? My thinking was "Consider x" is an introductory phrase, so it is OK to place the comma after it.

Comment: I think I might use a period, and then add a comma after "zero." Like so: "Consider x. When the regulator is set to zero, the integrand in x reduces to y." It would be even better if you could say, "Consider x > 0." Or "Consider x > 1." Or some other assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, that's a comma splice: two complete sentences joined by a comma. It's grammatically incorrect. You can use a colon to achieve the same effect:

"Consider x: when the regulator is set to zero the integrand in x reduces to y."